# merge RGB compontents together python

Tags: python, image, dataframe

I used a `split()` function on jpg image to get its red,green and blue components. Later, on these components i performed some filtering with K- means algorithm. The thing is I don't know how to put the image together after filtration.

I have a dataframe `image_df` as follows:

[image]

The input image was `(284, 321)`

The processing of orginal image is below:

```
x = np.arange(image.size[0])
y = np.arange(image.size[1])
xx,yy = np.meshgrid(x,y)
x_indices = xx.ravel()
y_indices = yy.ravel()

red, green, blue = image.split()
image_df= {}

image_df.update({'x_indices':x_indices})
image_df.update({'y_indices':y_indices})
image_df.update({'vec_red': np.array(red)[y_indices, x_indices]})
image_df.update({'vec_green':np.array(green)[y_indices, x_indices]})
image_df.update({'vec_blue': np.array(blue)[y_indices, x_indices]})
image_df = pd.DataFrame(image_df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cols = (image_df[['vec_red','vec_green','vec_blue']]).mean(axis=1)
cols = cols.to_numpy()
newimage= cols.reshape(321, 284)
plt.imshow(newimage)
```